# How to call a function in Matlab when two programs take input data from different directories?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to read output of one program into another program. But in each of these programs, I am using some input data which is being loaded from those respective directories. For example,
 In program 1, I load some text files and run the code for some array of outputs.
 In Program 2, I load some other text files and run the program. And in program 2 I also want to use data which is output of program 1.

Text files in program 1 and 2 are at different locations.
Can you suggest me to handle this issue?

Comment: specify the absolute path when you load the data i.e. `load('C:\....\myData.mat')`

Comment: This question has nothing to do with [tag:matlab-figure] (manipulation of graphical plots) or [tag:matlab-guide] (development of GUI applications).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you only need to use the absolute path to your files:

```
load('C:\...\dataFolder\dataFile.mat')
```

This way you can reach it independently on the current working folder in MATLAB.

Comment: @panini srikanth Please consider marking this as the solution if it solved your problem, so it will help others ;)